# Function in org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c-hook to compute/update nb of characters/words/lines in a section

Tags: org-mode

Did anybody ever program a lisp function to automatically compute and update the numbers of characters, words and/or line in a section?

In Orgmode, [/] in a section header is automatically updated to the number of [X] and [ ] in the list of the section. I would like to have {,,}  in a section header to be automatically updated to the number `c` of characters, `w` of words and `l` lines in the section, to read something like `{c characters, w words, l lines}`. Those values are easy to obtain using the function `count-words`, but I do not understand the format of functions added in `org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c-hook` (the list in my configuration is null, when there are definitely functions called when I press `C-c C-c`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pressing `C-c C-c` in Org mode runs the command `org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c` which does a wide range of things, depending on the context, in addition to calling two hooks: `org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c-hook` and `org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c-final-hook`. So it is not strange that things happen when pressing `C-c C-c` even though `org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c-hook` is nil.

The docstring of `org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c-hook` says the following:

> Each function will be called with no arguments.  The function
> must check if the context is appropriate for it to act.  If yes,
> it should do its thing and then return a non-nil value.  If the
> context is wrong, just do nothing and return nil.

Based an that you could use something like this:

```lisp
(defun my-update-section-wordcount ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (beginning-of-line)
    (when (and (org-at-heading-p)             
               (looking-at ".*{\\(.*?\\),\\(.*?\\),\\(.*?\\)}"))
      (let (start end chars words lines)
        (save-match-data
          (setq start (save-excursion (forward-line)(point))
                end (progn (org-end-of-subtree)(point))
                chars (- end start)
                words (count-words start end)
                lines (count-lines start end)))
        (replace-match (format "%d characters" chars) t nil nil 1)
        (replace-match (format " %d words" words) t nil nil 2)
        (replace-match (format " %d lines" lines) t nil nil 3))
      (message "Updated wordcount."))))

(add-hook 'org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c-hook 'my-update-section-wordcount)
```

This assumes you mean the whole subtree (everything until the next same-level heading or higher) starting at the heading when you say section, if you only want the entry (everything until the next heading of any level) replace `(progn (org-end-of-subtree)(point))` with `(org-entry-end-position)`. Also, due to the `(forward-line)` this excludes the heading itself.